# At operator vs numpy.matmul

Tags: python, numpy

Both `@` and `numpy.matmul` seem to do be the exact same thing and is suggested as the approach to perform matrix multiplication. Is there an actual difference between the two? The former is syntactically much shorter but those who aren't familiar might not know what the `@` operator, where as the latter is a bit more intuitive in what it's doing.

Comment: The doc says they are the same thing: [The @ operator can be used as a shorthand for np.matmul on ndarrays.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)

Comment: In python operators are translated by the interpreter into method calls.  The `a@b` is actually `a.__matmul__(b)`.  `np.matmul(a,b)` is just another way of doing the same thing.  Technically it's a `ufunc`, with some of the added methods and parameters common to other `ufunc`.  But for your purposes they are the same.

Comment: Similarly, `a+b` is the same as `np.add(a,b)`. (and `a.__add__(b)`).